# preg_match - как добавить исключение некоторых слов?

Tags: php

Всем привет.
Заранее всем благодарен!

Мне нужно сделать: если нашлось слово 'привет', то к этому слову нужна проверка слов (как|дела) и если эти слова есть, то в if не проваливаемся дальше, т.е к лову привет, нужны минус слова ко всей фразе.

```
$concepts_str = 'всем привет как дела';
if(preg_match( "/(всеммм|привет)/", $concepts_str) )
{
    $matches = 1;
}
```

Comment: так проще и искать запрещенные слова. Регулярки не всесильны..

Comment: Не очень ясна суть того что требуется, приведите пару примеров с фразами на входе и что вы хотите узнать из этих фраз на выходе

Comment: @Denis Startsev есть фраза 'всем привет как дела', находим слово "привет" - все ок. в эту всю штуку "/(всеммм|привет)/" нужно добавить минус слова, т.е ПРИВЕТ нашлось, но если есть слово КАК, то мы не проваливаемся в IF

Comment: сделай двухшаговую проверку